# Angular JS controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am a little confused in the syntax for the controller in angular js:
Both the following controller work when I use `{{` and `}}`.

Could someone tell me what is use of the parameters `$scope` and `$filter` before the `function($scope..)`, the one in bold. Also when I remove one of these, I dont get the output.
'MyController1', [**'$scope', '$filter**',function($scope

```
    app.controller('MyController1', ['$scope', '$filter',function($scope,    $filter) {
$scope.an = $filter('uppercase') ("ankurbhatia");

}]);
```

Here I have removed the `$scope` and `$filter` before the function but it still works.

```
app.controller('DemoController',
function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.an= $filter('uppercase')('Ari');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usefull if you minify your JavaScript. If you state the "stringified" variable before, the minified JS will still find what the minifed variable should be.

Your JavaScript minifed will be

```
app.controller("MyController1",["$scope","$filter",function(r,a){r.an=a("uppercase")("ankurbhatia")}]);
```

If you dont specify the string before, it will look like this:

```
app.controller("MyController1",function(o,r){o.an=r("uppercase")("ankurbhatia")});
```

Se the section "A Note on Minification"
 at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: To be specific: The DI knows what to inject because it knows what the variables are called in the code as a string. If you minify the code, you change the names of the variables and the DI no longer knows that it needs to inject those services.

Comment: Thanks a lot petur. So if I understood correctly, minification is all about saving some space by reducing the unnecessary characters from the source code, but in this case, where exactly are we saving the space?

Comment: When the JavaScript is transferred over the internet. For example, the whole angular.js file is 965,5kB unminified and 126,4kB minified, thats a lot of space to save in transferred files, and the user feels that the page loads faster.